# React components shrinking when empty and when loading from the server

Tags: reactjs, react-component

So Im building a shop in React and the problem im facing is that when the Shop component is loading the data  and when the Cart component is empty the components shrinks and don’t keep their "width: 100%" property

I think the problem started when I converted the components from class based to Hooks but I’m not sure where the problem comes from.

### my question :

How can i fix this and make my component not shrink?

what should add or remove?

and if you know where the problem is coming from  I will  like to learn.

this is the css code for them both :

```css
.cart_container{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20rem;
    background-color: burlywood;
    flex-direction: column;  
}
```

```css
.shopItem_container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

I will add the cart component so you can have a reference

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import './cart.css'
import { useIntersection } from 'react-use';
import formatCurrency from '../../../util'
import { Fade } from "react-awesome-reveal";


export default function Cart (props) {     
         
        const { cartItems } = props;
        
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="cart_container" >
       
                {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
                 <div className="cart cart_header"> 
                Cart Is Empty
                </div>
                    ) : (
                <div className="cart cart_header">
                     You Have {cartItems.length} Itames In The Cart{""}
                </div>
                )}
                
                
                <div > 
                    <div className="cart">
                        <Fade direction="up" triggerOnce cascade duration="750">
                        <ul className="cart_items">
                            {cartItems.map((item , index ) => (
                                <li key={index}>
                                    <div className="cart_image">
                                        <img src={item.image} alt={item.name}></img>
                                    </div> 
                                    <div className="ShopItem_details_discription">
                    <div className="productInfo_Container">
                            <div> LOGO </div>
                            <div className="productInfo">
                            <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                                <p>{item.info}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                                <p> Phone Number</p>
                                <div className="flourType_Container" >
                                    {item.flourType.map((x)=>(  
                                    <div>{" "}{x}</div>
                                    ))}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            
                        </div>
                                    <div className="cart_mengment">
                                       
                                        {formatCurrency(item.price)}
                                        <button onClick={() => props.addAmount(item)} className  = "Btn" > + </button>
                                        <button onClick={() => props.subAmount(item, index)} className  = "Btn" > - </button>
                                        <div className = "ItemCounte"> {item.count}</div>
                                        <button onClick={() => props.removeFromCart(index)}>
                                            Remove
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            ))}

                        </ul>
                        </Fade>
                    </div>
                </div>
              
            </div>
            </div>
            
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happened to me when I was beginning to code and learn, actually your code is working correctly, it is following the `width: 100%` statement, you need to look closely and you will realize that you wrote `width: 100%` not `width: 100vw`, so the css is actually taking the width of the div that you have, and when there is no data the div automatically shrinks down to 1px or so, remember that I said 1px not 1%, that is because that 1px is actually consider 100% width by the css since that is the full size of that div, so your css follows that width as its total 100% width and renders a shrunken div but when the content loads, the div actually gets bigger, getting filled by content and the div's size increases to lets say 100px and now the total 100% width of that div is 100px so now `width:100%` will render a 100px div.

The best react.js solution for this problem is to use a placeholder while the data is loading and when the data is done loading, you simply replace the placeholder with your actual content.

[Semantic UI has the perfect example](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/placeholder/#:%7E:text=4.0-,A%20placeholder%20is%20used%20to%20reserve%20space%20for%20content,will%20appear%20in%20a%20layout.&text=Placeholders%20can%20include%20PlaceholderParagraph%20%2C%20PlaceholderHeader,emulate%20the%20content%20being%20loaded.), but making a placeholder isn't complicated, you can proabably make one yourself with simple css and html

Comment: wow it worked thank you  , I will  look for the explanation on youtube, but i learned something  today so thanx. Also I didn't used the placeholder yet but i see way it useful so I will also look for a guid for that 